# Weird crosses in buttons FireFox and Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, windows-8.1

I got a new windows 8.1 installation and it keeps showing weird crosses in buttons in FireFox and Internet Explorer. (see picture) does anybody know how to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this happen with all sites?

Comment: Odd. What specific versions of those browsers ?

Comment: InternetExplorer 11 and the latest FireFox(downloaded it today)

Comment: In about every site it appears.

Comment: Does it happen with Chrome? Also, could you please post screenshots of say google.com (the entire page would help, so we could see if you're on HTTPS and what browser extensions are installed).

Comment: Stil unable to post images, so here is a link to the image: http://1drv.ms/1sMYhcq

Comment: In firefox it appears to be ok, but in IE it's really crap

Comment: Update your graphics driver to the latest version? This looks like a rendering issue. Just a guess.

Comment: You are my hero! Appearantly the system managers use a very buggy image to install our laptops... THANKYOU!